# ZF2 rest api coding style (camel-case or underscore)

Tags: php, api, rest, zend-framework2

I am writing the code with the following for mat in rest `api`.

I thought that, validation done in controller and the service layer cares of writing business logic and model takes care of database operations. I hope I am correct.

My clarification here is whether I can send `var_id` (underscore separated) to the service layer or as `varID` (camel-case).

I searched that lot of the `api` calls, most of them are `var_id`, that's the reason I used myself too.

But how can I use the variable here, because zend framework code works with camel-case, if am assigning the variables `varID = var_id` for each and every variable, is it right.

```
$dataSendToService = array(
    $varID = var_id,
    $varID2 = var_id2;
);
```

I am calling the `api` like the below in the create method.

http://128.12.788.88/api/v1/users/72

json get method like this

```
{
    "var_id":"var_value",
    "var_id1":"var_value1"
}
```

In controller:

```
function create() {

    $body = $this->getRequest()->getContent();

    $data = json_decode($body); 
    $id  = $this->params('id');

    //validation
    if( !isset( $data->pat_id ) || empty( $data->pat_id ) ) {
        $resp = array(
            'status' => 'failure',
            'errorCode' => 531, 
            'errorMessage' => 'Patient ID should not be empty'
        );
        return new JsonModel($resp);
    }


    if( !isset( $data->doc_id ) || empty($data->doc_id )) {
        $resp = array(
            'status' => 'failure', 
            'errorCode' => 532, 
            'errorMessage' => 'Doctor ID should not be empty'
        );
        return new JsonModel($resp);
    }

    if( !isset( $data->apt_time ) || empty($data->apt_time )) {
        $resp = array(
            'status' => 'failure',
            'errorCode' => 533, 
            'errorMessage' => 'Appointment time should not be empty');
        return new JsonModel($resp);
    }

    if( !isset( $data->apt_subject ) || empty($data->apt_subject )) {
        $resp = array(
            'status' => 'failure', 
            'errorCode' => 534, 
            'errorMessage' => 'Appointment Subject time should not be empty');
        return new JsonModel($resp);
    }

    $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $usersService = new UsersService($dbAdapter);
    $resp = $usersService->profile($data,$id);

}
```

In service:

```
function create() {

    //get the data and pass it to model

}
```

In model:

```
function create() {

    //get the data and insert in table and return the result       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is totally fine to use underscore separated values in `ZF2` but indeed camel-casing seems to be more common practice.

You definitely don't have to do all this manually, you can easily use filters for changing your `json` variables to camel-case:

```
use Zend\Filter\Word\CamelCaseToUnderscore;

...

$filter = new CamelCaseToUnderscore();
print $filter->filter('ThisIsMyContent');
```

And back to underscore separated:

```
use Zend\Filter\Word\CamelCaseToDash;

...    

filter = new CamelCaseToDash();
print $filter->filter('ThisIsMyContent');
```

If you use a `hydrator` then you can use [the ZF2 `ClassMethods`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Stdlib/Hydrator/ClassMethods.php) hydrator which can be set to `extract` and `hydrate` between both by passing a boolean to the constructor:

`underscore-separated` (true) or `camel-case` (false)

```
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods;

...

$boolean = true|false;
$hydrator = new ClassMethods($boolean)
```